# which solrconfig.xml file is it?

Tags: search, full-text-search, solr

i have just unzipped SOLR zip file downloaded from their website. and it says in the tutorial i have to edit the solrconfig.xml file. there are several in different locations.

which one is it? and where should i have this root folder? inside my web space?

```
LICENSE.txt  README.txt  client   contrib   docs   lib
CHANGES.txt  NOTICE.txt  build.xml  common-build.xml dist   example   src
```

ive got one in example/solr/conf. is it that one?

and about the data-config-xml. should i create one and then type in the path to it in solrconfig.xml? the tutorial isnt that descriptive.

Comment: Which of these environments are you working on:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall#Servlet_Container_or_Environment_Specific_Tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that's the directory

see here see here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall#Setup

The 2 files you'll have to edit at some point are:

- solr/conf/solrconfig.xml
- solr/conf/schema.xml

Which OS are you installing on? If it's windows then i can help you out.. as i've done it many times ;)

CraftyFella

Comment: in mac=) but now i have read a book on this issue in 300 pages. so its easier for me to set it up now:)

Comment: Cool.. I'd recommend this book also: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/#10+November+2009+-+Solr+1.4+Released I've read it... Like you wish i'd read it before i started working in Solr.

Answer (score 1):

The file you looking for is in this directory: **server/solr/new_core/conf/solrconfig.xml** (depending on your core name).

After changing it you should probably do `bin/solr restart`.

Answer (score 1):

For SolR 7.4.0 on CentOS and Red Hat, I found solrconfig.xml in /var/solr/data/[core_name]/conf.

Comment: @AlexanderI. Please don't abuse code formatting. I suggest you read [Should I use code blocks when mentioning framework names/technologies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360491/4284627) and [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538) It's OK to use code formatting on the file path, but "SolR", "CentOS" and "Red Hat" aren't code.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a New Core (Solr-8.6.2)**

```
sudo su solr -c '/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c <corename>'
or
sudo su solr -c '/opt/solr-8.6.2/bin/solr create -c <corename>'
```

**Core will be created at**

```
/var/solr/data/<corename>/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

Edit this XML to change your configuration